# Permitting JSON Array Parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Having a bit of trouble, im trying to permit array parameters and i've seen example of that...however I haven't seen an example where the array is an array of objects and the top level array is one of the main params being pulled in.

Sample JSON:

```
{
  "message_json": {
    "device": {
      "deviceid": "002"
    },
     "measurements": 
        [
            {
          "temp": 71.45,
          "humidity": 31.5
            },
            {
            "temp": 75.34,
            "humidity": 35.9
            }
        ]
  }
}
```

Functions for permitting:

```
   def device_params
      params[:message_json].fetch(:device, {}).permit(:deviceid)
   end

   def measurement_params
      params[:message_json].fetch(:measurements, {}).permit(:temp,:humidity)
   end
```

So the `measurement_params` does not work, and I know normally you'd do something like `array_obj: []` but this arrays object is already the `measurements` param thats getting fetched? How would I go about permitting these items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this:

```
def measurement_params
   params.require(:message_json).permit(measurements: [:temp, :humidity])
end
```

I am unable test this right now. But I was dealt with this problem and solved with this way.

Comment: That worked, looks like I was also able to combine them too `params.require(:message_json).permit(measurements: [:temp, :humidity], device: [:deviceid])` . Although im not sure how that would work with using `fetch` however if I wanted to use it.

Comment: Glad if helped. This one is called as nested params.  Fetch will work fine. But I am not on environmet right now.